# How to prove $W(T)$ is not a MVB estimator

Tags: parameter-estimation

A random sample $X_1, . . . , X_n$ of size n is taken from the Poisson distribution with parameter $\theta$.
Let $X = (X_1, . . . , X_n)^T$ and $x = (x_1, . . . , x_n)^T$.
It is proposed now to estimate the estimate the function of $\theta$, $g(\theta)$, where
$g(\theta) = P(X = k) = exp(−\theta)\theta^k/k!$
for a specified integer k greater than zero.

An unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
U(X_j) = 1,\quad X_j = k
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
U(X_j) = 0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{align*}
for a fixed $j$ $(j = 1, . . . , n)$.
On considering now without loss of generality the case $j = n$,
\begin{align*}
W(T) = E[U(X_n) | T]
\end{align*}
I know $W(T)$ is the UMVU estimator of $g(\theta)$, but I don't know how to prove that $W(T)$ is not a MVB (Minimum Variance Bound) estimator of $g(\theta)$. Could someone help me?